# What is template<> template<> syntax in the context of template-alias for?

Tags: c++, templates

(This question is not about template template arguments.)

I just discovered that GCC compiles such code

```
template <typename A, typename B>
struct P {};

template <typename A>
template <typename B>
using Q = P<A, B>;
```

where `Q` is a doubly-templated name.

But I can't use this. When I write `Q<short><long>`, I get

```
template_template.cpp:10:5: error: ‘Q<short int>’ is not a template
     Q<short><long>{};
     ^~~~~~~~
template_template.cpp:10:20: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘Q<short int>’
     Q<short><long>{};
                    ^
template_template.cpp:2:8: note: declaration of ‘Q<short int>’
 struct P {};
```

Why is the first snippet compiled?

Is there a syntax to convince the compiler that `Q<short>` is actually a template?

// GCC 6.3.0

Comment: "_Why is the first snippet compiled?_" Templates are compiled on usage. So if a template, or a method of a template is not used - it is not compiled.

Comment: Interestingly, `Q<short><long>` and `Q<short>` both crash every  MSVC compiler I could try it on.

Comment: Please always mention the *version* of your compiler. There are too many (versions of) GCC.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius: Agreed. It is not "compiled" if not used. But it is "parsed", and semantic-analysis is performed on the parsed code, right? If so, what *meaning* the semantic-analyzer makes out of it, from C++ spec point of view?

Comment: FYI my clang rejects the first snippet with `extraneous template parameter list in alias template declaration`

Comment: moreover, gcc ( up to trunk ) crazily accepts any `template <typename A1>
... template <typename AN> using Q = int;` yet resolving to int when used as Q<whatever> ( with no error ! )

Comment: It's actually possible to use this: https://wandbox.org/permlink/OI1cnadLm65ZBF9c.  Node that `template <typename B> using QQ1 = Q<int>; QQ1<char>` results in `P<char, int>` which I don't understand either

Comment: I hoped for a template template alias :(

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius, it is parsed, so it is syntactically correct, unlike `template <typename A> template <typename B> struct Q {};`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The C++14 standard says in 14p1:

> The *declaration* in a *template-declaration* shall
>   — declare or define a function, a class, or a variable, or
>   — define a member function, a member class, a member enumeration, or a static data member of a class template or of a class nested within a class template, or
>   — define a member template of a class or class template, or
>   — be an *alias-declaration*

Here the *declaration* within the *template-declaration* is none of the above (it is another *template-declaration*, which itself contains an *alias-declaration*), and therefore the code is invalid.

The relevant parts of the grammar are:

> *template-declaration*:
>       template <*template-parameter-list*> *declaration*
>   
>   *alias-declaration*:
>       using *identifier* *attribute-specifier-seq*<sub>opt</sub> = *type-id* ;

where a *declaration* can be a *template-declaration*, an *alias-declaration*, or other types of declarations.

Note that the grammar itself accepts the given code, but the additional restrictions in the text above make it invalid.

Comment: The grammar of *alias-declaration* would be of great help to understand the assertion you made that *"the code is invalid"*.

Comment: @Nawaz Added it. But the code is actually allowed by the grammar itself - it is the text quoted above that makes it invalid.

Comment: So basically *alias-declaration* cannot be a template (as per its grammar); *that* fact (along with the first quote) make the code invalid. Right?